# make two pictures stack next to text

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <head>
      <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">-->
      <style>
        body {
          background-image: url("https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/109/452/original/free-vector-red-poker-background.jpg");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
        
        #divChips {
          margin-top: 80vh;
          margin-left: 10vw;
          display: flex;
        }
        
        #imgChips {
          float: left;
        }
        
        #pChips {
          font-size: 3em;
          float: left;
          color: rgba(233, 197, 0, 1);
          border: 2px solid black;
          width: 15vh;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="divChips">
        <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/9510683d-ed33-4828-8a4a-a8d692134a4a/image-removebg-preview.png" id="imgChips">
        <p id="pChips">Chips: 0<br> Bet:0<img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/308a61bc-8321-483b-a63f-70a8a1221450/image-removebg-preview.png" style="height: 1.75vh; width: 1.75vw; margin-bottom: 1vh; display: block;"><img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/308a61bc-8321-483b-a63f-70a8a1221450/image-removebg-preview.png" style="height: 1.75vh; width: 1.75vw; transform: rotate(180deg); display: block;"></p>
      </div>
      <!--<script src="./poker.js"></script>-->
    </body>

    </html>
```

The display block causes the two arrows to show up underneath of bet: 0

Is there any way I can make the arrows show up next to bet: 0
I've tried to do some research but I don't really know any key words to say what I need

Comment: either keep the default `display: inline` or wrap them in a container and use flexbox...